# R mutate & gsub where pattern is based on a column

Tags: r, gsub, dplyr, rowwise

I am trying to remove `pattern` from `var_1` using `mutate()` and `gsub()`.

As `gsub()` only takes a string, I have to use `rowwise()` before the `mutate()`. Otherwise it will only use the first record from the `pattern` column.

I am wondering if there is any other method to achieve the same result without using `rowwise()` as it slows the process quite a bit.

```
test <- data.frame(
  var_1 = c('1AB', '2AB', '3C')
  ,pattern = c('AB','A','C')
)

test %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate( result = sub(pattern, '', var_1)
          )
```

Desired results:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  var_1 var_2 pattern result
  <chr> <lgl> <chr>   <chr> 
1 1AB   FALSE AB      1     
2 2AB   TRUE  A       2B    
3 3C    FALSE C       3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `stringr` options which are vectorized.

Using `str_remove` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test %>% mutate(result = str_remove(var_1, pattern))

#  var_1 pattern result
#1   1AB      AB      1
#2   2AB       A     2B
#3    3C       C      3
```

this is same as using `str_replace` with replacement as `""`.

```
test %>%  mutate(result = str_replace(var_1, pattern, ''))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I was trying to compare mutate + str_replace  and with + str_replace and it seems like  mutate + str_replace is much slower. Do you know why that's the case (see code in my next comment) ?

Comment: microbenchmark::microbenchmark(

test %>% 
  mutate( 
    temp = stringr::str_remove(string = var_1
                               ,pattern = pattern
    )
  )

,with(test,
      stringr::str_remove(string = var_1
                          ,pattern = pattern
      )
  )


, times = 10L
)

Comment: I am not actually aware if `mutate` adds an additional overhead. You are testing this on how many rows of data?

Comment: I was using the same dataframe as defined above so 3 rows and the `mutate` method takes at least 10 times longer than the `with` approach

Comment: You cannot get any meaningful results with 3 rows. Expand your data to altleast 10k rows and then test.

Comment: Ah you are right. They look similar when increased to 10k rows

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
test %>% 
      mutate(result = map2_chr(var_1, pattern, ~ sub(.y, '', .x)))
```